# How to create fast and efficient filestream writes on large sparse files

Tags: c#, file-io, filestream, sparse-matrix

I have an application that writes large files in multiple segments. I use FileStream.Seek to position each wirte. It appears that when I call FileStream.Write at a deep position in a sparse file the write triggers a "backfill" operation (writeing 0s) on all preceding bytes which is slow.

Is there a more efficient way of handling this situation?

The below code demonstrates the problem. The initial write takes about 370 MS on my machine.

```
    public void WriteToStream()
    {
        DateTime dt;
        using (FileStream fs = File.Create("C:\\testfile.file"))
        {   
            fs.SetLength(1024 * 1024 * 100);
            fs.Seek(-1, SeekOrigin.End);
            dt = DateTime.Now;
            fs.WriteByte(255);              
        }

        Console.WriteLine(@"WRITE MS: " + DateTime.Now.Subtract(dt).TotalMilliseconds.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

NTFS does support [Sparse Files](http://www.flexhex.com/docs/articles/sparse-files.phtml), however there is no way to do it in .net without p/invoking some native methods.

It is not very hard to mark a file as sparse, just know once a file is marked as a sparse file it can never be converted back in to a non sparse file except by coping the entire file in to a new non sparse file.

Example useage

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern bool DeviceIoControl(
        SafeFileHandle hDevice,
        int dwIoControlCode,
        IntPtr InBuffer,
        int nInBufferSize,
        IntPtr OutBuffer,
        int nOutBufferSize,
        ref int pBytesReturned,
        [In] ref NativeOverlapped lpOverlapped
    );

    static void MarkAsSparseFile(SafeFileHandle fileHandle)
    {
        int bytesReturned = 0;
        NativeOverlapped lpOverlapped = new NativeOverlapped();
        bool result =
            DeviceIoControl(
                fileHandle,
                590020, //FSCTL_SET_SPARSE,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                0,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                0,
                ref bytesReturned,
                ref lpOverlapped);
        if(result == false)
            throw new Win32Exception();
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        //Use stopwatch when benchmarking, not DateTime
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        stopwatch.Start();
        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(@"e:\Test\test.dat"))
        {
            MarkAsSparseFile(fs.SafeFileHandle);

            fs.SetLength(1024 * 1024 * 100);
            fs.Seek(-1, SeekOrigin.End);
            fs.WriteByte(255);
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();

        //Returns 2 for sparse files and 1127 for non sparse
        Console.WriteLine(@"WRITE MS: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds); 
    }
}
```

---

Once a file has been marked as sparse it now behaves like you excepted it to behave in the comments too. You don't need to write a byte to mark a file to a set size.

```
static void Main()
{
    string filename = @"e:\Test\test.dat";

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
    {
        MarkAsSparseFile(fs.SafeFileHandle);

        fs.SetLength(1024 * 1024 * 25);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response, this is very interesting. I was under the impression that FileStream.SetLength() created a sparse file. Am I wrong about that?

I am trying to avoid the performance hit incurred when writing to a sparse file at a large seek point. I am not totally clear on how this would avoid that issue.

Comment: Internally SetLength is calling [SetEndOfFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365531%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) . I don't know if that is creating a sparse file or not.

Comment: Just ran a quick test, it does not.

Comment: @user1385998 This is much easier to do than I thought! See my updated Post.

Comment: Got it! Thanks so much for all the detail and information (not to mention the nice bug catch in the SparseFile code). The added detail that once you create the file as sparse it remains sparse on subsequent opens is exactly what I need.

Comment: Question, is it necessary to set the length? Or could you at that point just do a seek and a write?

Comment: @PhonicUK I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code to use sparse files:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;

public static class SparseFiles
{
    private const int FILE_SUPPORTS_SPARSE_FILES = 64;

    private const int FSCTL_SET_SPARSE = 0x000900c4;

    private const int FSCTL_SET_ZERO_DATA = 0x000980c8;

    public static void MakeSparse(this FileStream fileStream)
    {
        var bytesReturned = 0;
        var lpOverlapped = new NativeOverlapped();
        var result = DeviceIoControl(
            fileStream.SafeFileHandle, 
            FSCTL_SET_SPARSE, 
            IntPtr.Zero, 
            0, 
            IntPtr.Zero, 
            0, 
            ref bytesReturned, 
            ref lpOverlapped);

        if (!result)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }
    }

    public static void SetSparseRange(this FileStream fileStream, long fileOffset, long length)
    {
        var fzd = new FILE_ZERO_DATA_INFORMATION();
        fzd.FileOffset = fileOffset;
        fzd.BeyondFinalZero = fileOffset + length;
        var lpOverlapped = new NativeOverlapped();
        var dwTemp = 0;

        var result = DeviceIoControl(
            fileStream.SafeFileHandle, 
            FSCTL_SET_ZERO_DATA, 
            ref fzd, 
            Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(FILE_ZERO_DATA_INFORMATION)), 
            IntPtr.Zero, 
            0, 
            ref dwTemp, 
            ref lpOverlapped);
        if (!result)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }
    }

    public static bool SupportedOnVolume(string filename)
    {
        var targetVolume = Path.GetPathRoot(filename);
        var fileSystemName = new StringBuilder(300);
        var volumeName = new StringBuilder(300);
        uint lpFileSystemFlags;
        uint lpVolumeSerialNumber;
        uint lpMaxComponentLength;

        var result = GetVolumeInformationW(
            targetVolume, 
            volumeName, 
            (uint)volumeName.Capacity, 
            out lpVolumeSerialNumber, 
            out lpMaxComponentLength, 
            out lpFileSystemFlags, 
            fileSystemName, 
            (uint)fileSystemName.Capacity);
        if (!result)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }

        return (lpFileSystemFlags & FILE_SUPPORTS_SPARSE_FILES) == FILE_SUPPORTS_SPARSE_FILES;
    }

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool DeviceIoControl(
        SafeFileHandle hDevice, 
        int dwIoControlCode, 
        IntPtr InBuffer, 
        int nInBufferSize, 
        IntPtr OutBuffer, 
        int nOutBufferSize, 
        ref int pBytesReturned, 
        [In] ref NativeOverlapped lpOverlapped);

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool DeviceIoControl(
        SafeFileHandle hDevice, 
        int dwIoControlCode, 
        ref FILE_ZERO_DATA_INFORMATION InBuffer, 
        int nInBufferSize, 
        IntPtr OutBuffer, 
        int nOutBufferSize, 
        ref int pBytesReturned, 
        [In] ref NativeOverlapped lpOverlapped);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetVolumeInformationW")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool GetVolumeInformationW(
        [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpRootPathName, 
        [Out] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder lpVolumeNameBuffer, 
        uint nVolumeNameSize, 
        out uint lpVolumeSerialNumber, 
        out uint lpMaximumComponentLength, 
        out uint lpFileSystemFlags, 
        [Out] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder lpFileSystemNameBuffer, 
        uint nFileSystemNameSize);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct FILE_ZERO_DATA_INFORMATION
    {
        public long FileOffset;

        public long BeyondFinalZero;
    }
}
```

And sample code to test the above class.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream("test", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
        {
            fileStream.SetLength(1024 * 1024 * 128);
            fileStream.MakeSparse();
            fileStream.SetSparseRange(0, fileStream.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: NOTE: Windows Explorer does not know how to copy sparse files. It will copy all the 0 byte data as actual 0 byte data. So if you want to maintain sparseness, you should probably keep some metadata in your file about sparse regions so you can restore them after an administrator (user) copies the file.