# Create a fixed size file in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, io

Is there a way in .NET to create a file with specific size without having to write to it?

I need to be able to write at specific position leaving empty space as needed. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean "create a file without having to write it"?  If you don't write it to the file system, it's not a file.  Can you clarify?

Comment: What do you mean by "empty space"?  Is this an ASCII file that should have a fixed number of characters, and any characters you don't explicitly write to the file should be spaces?

Comment: @David - I'm trying to create a file that is empty but reserves space on disc.

Comment: @ArturoMartinez: I imagine *something* would have to be written to the disk.  "Empty" may be a misnomer here.  You could create a byte array of any length, fill it with any bytes (white space for example), and write that to the disk.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98774/preallocating-file-space-in-c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may not know it, but you may be asking this question "How do I create sparse files in .Net?" See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817746/how-to-create-fast-and-efficient-filestream-writes-on-large-sparse-files)

The short answer is that you cannot create sparse files using managed code, however, you can using the native API's -- the problem is that sparse files "remain sparse". So, if you want to backfill later, you are probably better off not doing this. You can use an open FileStream and call SetLength() If you just want to avoid the detail of writing out explicit the explicit filler to your file, the O/S will still fill the "empty" portion of your file with NULs

```
public override void SetLength(
    long value
)
```

ADDED

Note that the file is not necessarily physically extended on disk at this instance. But if you read from the "tail gap" you will get NULs and if you write to the gap, the O/S will backfill the intervening space with NULs. NTFS maintains "valid length" and "file length" seperately. Calling SetLength does not change the valid length, just the file length. The "tail gap" is the region of the file spanning from the valid length and the file length. Note also that setting the valid length is supported by Windows. Writing to the tail gap or end of file also updates the valid length.

So, you may avoid a performance hit by not having to actually extend the file immediately, but sooner or later the O/S will have to take the time to backfill with NUL filled blocks (and setting the valid length to the new write position), possibly leaving a smaller tail gap when you write to the tail gap.

Note that getting random blocks of existing data from the disk when you extend a file would be a security issue -- imagine getting payroll data with SSNs.

If Windows ever adds a new file system the exact behavior could become even more complicated, but is would presumably be at least as good as what happens on NTFS.

Comment: Realized my answer was not really complete, so I added to it.

Comment: ntfs fills files with NULs ? really?

Answer (score 0):

A file is a series of bytes on disk, which in different formats have different parts, like header, body, etc. Thus there is no such a thing as empty file. Because each byte is reserved and each byte (or two-bytes in Unicode) would represent a character. Even in its initial state.

So, technically speaking what you want is to reserve a amount of space on disk, so that you can write there later.

Now if you don't want to have readable or visible characters in that file, you can simply create an file that is filled with many whitespace characters.

Comment: so you just write a bunch of space characters? what about a file of 100MB? Isn't there another way to reserve space?

Comment: A file with 100MBs is simply 100 * 1024 * 1024 bytes reserved on disk. Now whatever written in each byte, OS doesn't care. It simply takes the space on disk.

Comment: So the only answer is to Write `new byte[1] { 0 }` n number of times?

Comment: Seems that @GaryWalker's answer is more appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write it anyway

```
File.WriteAllText(path,new String(' ',size));
```

Then you can `seek` to a particular position and write..